# Remote Desktop For Mac

Tags: osx, remote-access

TeamViewer was my original option, but I want to have a application like Microsoft Remote Desktop which connects to the computer and the connected computer's screen will be locked. So no one sees my actions. Can anyone suggest a application which does the same thing? Thanks!

Comment: Can you specify the OS of the client and server? Both Mac OS X?

Comment: They are both Mac OS X

Answer (score 4):

You can use [Apple Remote Desktop 3](http://www.apple.com/remotedesktop/):

- non-free
- Mac OS X
- has a [Curtain Mode](http://www.apple.com/remotedesktop/newfeatures.html#curtainmode):

> For those times when you want your actions to be hidden from the end
>   user, there’s Curtain Mode. This allows you to block the view behind a
>   virtual curtain, while retaining full control of the screen. It’s
>   perfect for those working on public-facing systems.

---

Note that RealVNC does work on Mac and can blank the remote computer's display when you connect but this option is [not currently available on Windows 8.x, Mac OS X or UNIX/Linux](https://support.realvnc.com/Knowledgebase/Article/View/267/6/can-i-blank-the-remote-computers-display-when-i-connect).

Answer (score 1):

If both computers are on OS X (or Linux I suppose) you can use the built-in VNC capability of OS X.

You can activate VNC in `System Preferences` > `Sharing`.
There activate `Remote Management`, click `Computer Settings` and activate VNC.

[image: Activate VNC in Sharing Preferences]

Then click the `Options...` button to define exactly what remote logged in users are allowed to do on your Mac.

Now go to your other Mac from which you want to access the screen of the target Mac. There open Finder and select `Connect to server...` from the `Go To` menu or just press `cmd-K` on your keyboard.

Enter the IP address of your target Mac prefixed with `vnc://` and press OK. You will be connected to the target Mac. You will be asked for a username and password. Here enter a local user and password of the target Mac.

This is also described in more detail in [this blog post.](http://mr-fridge.de/blog/you-dont-need-remote-desktop-vnc-is-built-in)

You can also run VNC client from Safari or directly from the command line, e.g.

```
open vnc://<host>:<port>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [FreeRDP](http://www.freerdp.com/), which is a free remote desktop protocol library and clients. Check out the [GitHub page](https://github.com/FreeRDP/FreeRDP).

Install via Brew: `brew install freerdp`.